# DeepLearning4J: wrong shape of weights array

Tags: python, java, tensorflow, keras, deeplearning4j

I have a model that was constructed and trained with Tensorflow in Python, and I need to use it in Java with Eclipse. Its configuration looks as follows:

```
### define model
model = keras.Sequential()

## leakage of the leaky relu
LRU = 0.01

### the first set of convolutional layers
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=6, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same", input_shape=(6, 1)))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=12, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=48, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))

### the second set of convolutional layers
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=24, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.02))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=12, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.01))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=6, kernel_size=2, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LRU))

model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
```

For better readability, the output of `model.summary()` is:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 6, 6)              18        
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)      (None, 6, 6)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 5, 6)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 5, 12)             156       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 5, 12)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 4, 12)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 4, 24)             600       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 4, 24)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 3, 24)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 3, 48)             2352      
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 3, 48)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 2, 48)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 2, 24)             2328      
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 2, 24)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 2, 24)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_5 (Conv1D)            (None, 2, 12)             588       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 2, 12)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 2, 12)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_6 (Conv1D)            (None, 2, 6)              150       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_6 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 2, 6)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 12)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 6,192
Trainable params: 6,192
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I saved the trained model with `model.save('my_model.h5')`. In Eclipse I am using *DeepLearning4J* as it provides keras features. I load the model with

```
MultiLayerNetwork model = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights('my_model.h5');
```

The output of `model.summary()` in Eclipse is:

```
=======================================================================================
LayerName (LayerType)                  nIn,nOut   TotalParams   ParamsShape            
=======================================================================================
conv1d (Convolution1DLayer)            1,6        18            b:{1,6}, W:{6,1,2,1}   
leaky_re_lu (ActivationLayer)          -,-        0             -                      
max_pooling1d (Subsampling1DLayer)     -,-        0             -                      
conv1d_1 (Convolution1DLayer)          6,12       156           b:{1,12}, W:{12,6,2,1} 
leaky_re_lu_1 (ActivationLayer)        -,-        0             -                      
max_pooling1d_1 (Subsampling1DLayer)   -,-        0             -                      
conv1d_2 (Convolution1DLayer)          12,24      600           b:{1,24}, W:{24,12,2,1}
leaky_re_lu_2 (ActivationLayer)        -,-        0             -                      
max_pooling1d_2 (Subsampling1DLayer)   -,-        0             -                      
conv1d_3 (Convolution1DLayer)          24,48      2,352         b:{1,48}, W:{48,24,2,1}
leaky_re_lu_3 (ActivationLayer)        -,-        0             -                      
max_pooling1d_3 (Subsampling1DLayer)   -,-        0             -                      
conv1d_4 (Convolution1DLayer)          48,24      2,328         b:{1,24}, W:{24,48,2,1}
leaky_re_lu_4 (ActivationLayer)        -,-        0             -                      
dropout (DropoutLayer)                 -,-        0             -                      
conv1d_5 (Convolution1DLayer)          24,12      588           b:{1,12}, W:{12,24,2,1}
leaky_re_lu_5 (ActivationLayer)        -,-        0             -                      
dropout_1 (DropoutLayer)               -,-        0             -                      
conv1d_6 (Convolution1DLayer)          12,6       150           b:{1,6}, W:{6,12,2,1}  
leaky_re_lu_6 (ActivationLayer)        -,-        0             -                      
flatten_loss (LossLayer)               -,-        0             -                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Total Parameters:  6,192
        Trainable Parameters:  6,192
           Frozen Parameters:  0
=======================================================================================
```

Now I am trying to use the network for prediction at one specific input (the required  shape using 1 input is (1,6,1) by construction):

```
INDArray input = Nd4j.create(new double[][][] {{{0.0702},{0.1191},{0.1702},{0.1310},{0.2248},{0.3205}}});
```

Running the command

```
INDArray output = model.output(input,false);
```

now causes the following error:

```
Error at [/home/runner/work/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/libnd4j/include/ops/declarable/generic/nn/convo/conv1d.cpp:70:0]:
CUSTOM CONV1D OP: wrong shape of weights array, expected is [2, 3, 12], but got [2, 6, 12] instead !
Exception in thread "main" 14:04:45.925 [main] ERROR org.nd4j.linalg.cpu.nativecpu.ops.NativeOpExecutioner - Failed to execute op conv1d. Attempted to execute with 3 inputs, 1 outputs, 0 targs,0 bargs and 6 iargs. Inputs: [(FLOAT,[1,3,5],c), (FLOAT,[2,6,12],c), (FLOAT,[12],c)]. Outputs: [(FLOAT,[1,12,5],c)]. tArgs: -. iArgs: [2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]. bArgs: -. Op own name: "d3142824-92ad-41c4-99e0-1111f4f75a5f" - Please see above message (printed out from c++) for a possible cause of error.
```

I really can't wrap my head around why it expects weights of shape is [2, 3, 12]? That appears nowhere in the `summary()` command...

Does anyone have an idea about what is going wrong here?

EDIT: I tried to do the same in Python and everything seems to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input = np.array(0.0702,0.1191,0.1702,0.1310,0.2248,0.3205)
input = input.reshape((1,6,1))

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
model.predict(input)
```

gives the output

```
array([[0.01571162, 0.02778796, 0.07743346, 0.1355067 , 0.19171888,
        0.25232363, 0.32630318, 0.3799559 , 0.42786202, 0.46094775,
        0.50001675, 0.54188776]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with cnn 1d import specifically.

For posterity, what was happening was the expected number of channels was actually twice the amount it was actually supposed to be. This was a bug and has been fixed.

It's been documented here:
https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues/9476

Fix here: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/pull/9477

Once this fix is merged, you may either use snapshots or as a workaround try our tensorflow import instead.

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for the clarification! I'll try the suggested workaround during the upcoming week.